# The right possessive pronoun for "one"?

Tags: pronouns, possessive-pronouns

Is it ok to use "their" as a general reference to the pronoun "one"? For example in a sentence as follows:

> One should be aware of the differences between spreadsheets and databases to choose the right one for their case.

Comment: Yes. Their can be used for both singular and plural subjects, and it's also gender neutral.

Comment: Many thanks VKBoy.

Comment: 'Grammatical possessives are 'their' and 'one's', but use 'their' if you don't wish to sound rarefied ('rarefied' itself sounds rarefied, but more common synonyms would sound harsher). 'One's' is distinctly second best in this particular example.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes and "non-duplicate" closevotes. The "original" of this question has been well-received here on ELU for over 8 years, and I think it's unreasonable to expect *every* new querant to be able to find any pre-existing instances of their question.